# How can I reschedule my LocalNotification on device reboot without user opening my app?

Tags: codenameone

Android has this user permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`
which invokes a BroadcastReceiver but I can't figure out how to use it with my LocalNotification without using native interface.

Comment: I think this should be seamless, if it isn't automatically rescheduled we probably need to provide a way to do this. We'll get back to you on this.

Comment: Ok Shai, will be expecting your reply.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this isn't supported at this time, you can probably achieve this with a native interface but obviously this isn't ideal. Please file an RFE on this and we will evaluate it for 3.8 as it's too late in the cycle for 3.7